# Set session in Request for node js unit test

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai, supertest

I have a route    `.route(myapp/profile)
  .get(myProfileMiddleware.checkAccessToken(),
    myProfileController.getProfile
  )`

Here the middleware method

> checkAccessToken

checks whether a session token is set as below.

```
checkAccessToken() { 
return (req, rex, next) => {      
  if (!req.session || !req.session.accessToken) {
   // throws 403 Forbidden error
  }
  // Executes next() method      
}}
```

If the access token is present the route executes the corresponding controller method `myProfileController.getProfile`, else throws 403 forbidden error.

I need to write the unit test for this route. I am using **mocha, chai , sinon and supertest**. 
I tried to set the session variable in request method using "**express-session**" as below

```
app.use(session({accessToken: 'ssshhhhh'}));
```

Also tried     set('cookie', ['accessToken=sssh'], but didnt work. The session token is not getting set and the route shows `403 Forbidden` error

Could anybody have a working solution for this? Thanks in advance.

I am using the below versions:

**Node : 8.7, chai: ^4.1.0, mocha: ^5.0.4, node-mocks-http: ^1.6.6, sinon:^2.3.2
supertest: ^3.0.0**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but when I use `node-mocks-http` I set the session when I create the mockedRequest in the test file.

```
const mockRequest = httpMocks.createRequest({
  session: { … }
});
```

Then that allows the actual route handler to set session properties.

See [the docs](https://github.com/howardabrams/node-mocks-http#api) about `.createRequest()` and notice the `session` option.